# How do I create a stored procedure in heidisql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, heidisql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in heidisql (mysql).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_FORM20_POST(
    P_SESSIONID     VARCHAR(256)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbForm20
        ( SESSIONID, RegDT)
    VALUES
        ( P_SESSIONID, NOW()); 
END
```

This is my query. I'm trying to create this procedure, but occur some error:

> Error code is 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near'' at line 8".

However, I don't know wrong syntax. What is wrong?

I want to success in heidisql tool. I don't want other db tool.
Please help me.

Comment: Did you solve this yet? Do you have any feedback on my answer? You are new and have not marked any answers yet with the Green check mark showing the question is answered (if that is the case).

Comment: I'm sorry too late. It still occur same error. So I'm using toad for mysql instead of heidisql. Thank you for your answer. Good day!!

Answer (score 3):

The problem in that query is the semicolon, which is the default query delimiter.

In order to change the delimiter in HeidiSQL, add the DELIMITER client command above the `CREATE PROCEDURE` query:

```
DELIMITER \\
SELECT 1\\
CREATE PROCEDURE ...\\
DELIMITER ;
```

HeidiSQL also has a procedure designer, with no need to set the delimiter:

[image: HeidiSQL procedure designer]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this. The database reads the `;` in your code as an end of the procedure. You probably don't intend it like that :). The `DELIMITER` command takes care of that by changing `;` to something customizable, like `$$`. Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_FORM20_POST(
    P_SESSIONID     VARCHAR(256)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbForm20
        ( SESSIONID, RegDT)
    VALUES
        ( P_SESSIONID, NOW()); 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_FORM20_POST(
    P_SESSIONID     VARCHAR(256)
)

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbForm20
        ( SESSIONID, RegDT)
    VALUES
        ( P_SESSIONID, NOW());

END //

DELIMITER;
```

Comment: How is this answer any different from the most upvoted one?

Comment: @user1781290 old comment, but this answer sets the delimiter back to `;` while the most upvoted leaves it as `$$`.